# Debug an iOS app while keeping existing data

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I'm currently having a problem with an iOS app that we've only observed in production, in the App Store version.

I'm trying to test it by debugging a development version of the app from Xcode, with the same Bundle ID and everything, but it removes the existing App Store app before running the development version, hence removing all traces of the bug.

Is there any way to instruct Xcode not to remove an existing app when debugging?

P.S. My app is a Cordova app. I already tried attaching a Safari Web Inspector, but it turns out it doesn't detect published apps.

Comment: No way. If the bundle ID's are the same, the new app will replace the old one.

Comment: @Joerg, so it seems I'm stuck, right?

Comment: yes. But I don't see your problem. You have two choices: Change during development the Bundle ID or do some reverse engineering for creating a "new" app, if you don't have the original code. It is not difficult to get the code and all the other stuff from an existing cordova app.

Comment: @Joerg, The app is mine, I don't need reverse engineering. But changing the Bundle ID for development gives me a new installation, and I need to test the existing installation. Sure, I can try to trigger the error in the new one, but I don't even know what it is. That's why I want to debug the existing one.

Comment: @Joerg, I forgot to say. I'm saving data both in localStorage and using the ContentSync plugin.